# Beginner Hangman Game : Can't make it work

Tags: python

I just started coding (on Python 3) the day before yesterday (which makes me a SERIOUS newbie) and I figured out I'd try to make my own Hangman Game, but well I just don't know what's wrong with what I've done so far! ^_^ This is it:

```
L = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0,len(L))
w = L[random_index]
W = list(w)
a = input()
tries = 1
print(W)
while len(W) != 0 and tries<10:
    if a in W:
        print("yes")
        W.remove(a)
        tries += 1
        a = input()
    elif a not in W:
        print("no") 
        tries += 1
        a = input()
else:
    if len(W) == 0: 
        print("Well done! Your word was")
        print(w) 
    elif tries == 10:
        print("You died!")
```

I think the problem comes from my loop thingy " while len(W) != 0 ", because everything is fine with the input part, it just doesn't stop when it should! (meaning when there is supposed to be nothing left to guess!) 
So I hope someone would be nice enough to waste two minutes of his day helping me with my basic-not-so-interesting problem! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to actually describe what happens (and what you expected to happen instead). Also you should try to debug this yourself first (e.g.: by adding `print` statements where you suspect the error to be)

Comment: While not the best solution, you could always add a `break` to your exit statement for the while loop... I tend to avoid using multiple logic statements in a while loop for this very reason.  Again, probably not the best solution, but...

Comment: Your code should ask for a new input at the beginning of every loop, not the end.

Comment: @UnholySheep _"it just doesn't stop when it should! (meaning when there is supposed to be nothing left to guess!)"_ That's a clear enough description, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

- you can have variable names of more than one letter
- `random.choice(L)` is easier than `L[random.randrange(len(L))]`

so

```
from random import choice

def show_word(target_word, remaining_letters, blank="-"):
    print("".join(blank if ch in remaining_letters else ch.upper() for ch in target_word))

words = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
target_word = choice(words)
remaining_letters = set(target_word)

print("Let's play Hangman!")

for round in range(1, 11):
    show_word(target_word, remaining_letters)
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").strip().lower()
    if guess in remaining_letters:
        print("You got one!")
        remaining_letters.remove(guess)
        if not remaining_letters:
            break
    else:
        print("Sorry, none of those...")

if remaining_letters:
    print("You died!")
else:
    print("You solved {}! Well done!".format(target_word.upper()))
```

Comment: Expert way to do it, nice. Plus one! :D

Answer (score 0):

When you guessed the last letter at the end of the previous loop, the current loop will tell you the guess is correct and then ask for another letter.  Try something more like this

```
L = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0,len(L))
w = L[random_index]
W = list(w)
tries = 0
print(W)
while len(W) != 0 and tries<10:
    a = input()
    if a in W:
        print("yes")
        W.remove(a)
        tries += 1
    elif a not in W:
        print("no") 
        tries += 1
else:
    if len(W) == 0: 
        print("Well done! Your word was")
        print(w) 
    elif tries == 10:
        print("You died!")
```

Comment: You can remove `elif` and use `else`. And `tries+=1` could be common for both `if` and `else`

Comment: Thanks a lot! My a=input() was just misplaced! ^_^

Comment: @kuro yeah, but those aren't really logical changes and I didn't want to clutter my answer

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, understood. Just thought it will be worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you can solve your issue like this, also remember you can give info to the user adding a prompt in the input method:

```
L = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0,len(L))
w = L[random_index]
W = list(w)
tries = 1
print(W)
while len(W) != 0 and tries<10:
  a = input("select word")
  if a in W:
    print("yes")
    W.remove(a)
    tries += 1
  else:
    print("no") 
    tries += 1

  if len(W) == 0: 
    print("Well done! Your word was")
    print(w)
  elif tries == 10:
    print("You died!")
```